# Can't bind to 'customClass' since it isn't a known property of 'tree-view'

Tags: angular

I installed ng2 treeview package using guidelines which is provided by  https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-tree-view .Now, i am getting the following error while running my code.
Here is the error:

```
      Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
      Can't bind to 'customClass' since it isn't a known property of 'tree-view'.
      1. If 'tree-view' is an Angular component and it has 'customClass' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
      2. If 'tree-view' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
       ("
  <tree-view (onNodeSelected)="selectedNode($event)" [ERROR ->][customClass]="'my-custom-class'" [nodes]="sampleNodes"></tree-view>
"): ProjetcEditComponent@1:57
    Can't bind to 'nodes' since it isn't a known property of 'tree-view'.
      1. If 'tree-view' is an Angular component and it has 'nodes' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
      2. If 'tree-view' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
     ("
  <tree-view (onNodeSelected)="selectedNode($event)" [customClass]="'my-custom-class'" [ERROR ->][nodes]="sampleNodes"></tree-view>
"): ProjetcEditComponent@1:91
    'tree-view' is not a known element:
   1. If 'tree-view' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
   2. If 'tree-view' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show us you app.module.ts, and component + template code that is using the ng2-tree-view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just removed the "nodes:" from the code(inside the constructor) and its working fine.